# How can i accept argument after invoking a method in transcript on Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: methods, arguments, smalltalk, workspace, pharo

I have created a Game class, and I have a method called Board which must accept stdin of 2 integers, and 1 integer will be assigned to the column variable, and the other integer will be assigned to the row variable. So for example, opening up Transcript on pharo and typing this in:

'Game new board 2 3'

should make column=2 and row =3 but I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is my code attempt

```
 board

| col rows |

col := stdin nextNumber

rows := stdin nextNumber

Transcript cr; show: col asString, rows asString
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK. I have to create a board game and I cant even figure out how to accept arguments from the transcript/workspace and I'm screwed it's due next monday!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show you the idiomatic way. If you type in your playground

> Game newBoardColumns: 2 rows: 3

and then DoIt and go, a debugger will pop up telling you that that `#newBoardColumns:rows:`message is not understood by the Game. In your debugger, you have a create button that allows you to add that method. If you select to add it on the class side of Game, you can implement it as something like

```
newBoardColumns: aColumns rows: aRows
    ^self basicNew
    initializeColumns: aColumns rows: aRows;
    yourself
```

That will return a new instance of the Game class, and initialize it with the columns and rows method. If you save that and restart execution in the debugger, it will complain that it doesn't know `#initializeColumns:rows:` so you'll have to create that in the same way, this time at the instance side of Game.

```
initializeColumns: aColumns rows: aRows
    columns := aColumns.
    rows := aRows. 
    self initialize.
```

when trying to save, make sure to add `columns` and `rows` as instance variables. Now you can restart execution again and inspect your Game in the inspector pane.

To show something in the Transcript, you could type in your playground

> (Game newBoardColumns: 2 rows: 3) show

and DoIt. That will pop up a debugger again, telling you that `#show` is not understood. You can implement that in Game as

```
show
    Transcript cr; show: columns asString,' ', rows asString
```

Answer (score 2):

The Transcript is more like a logging stream, not an interactive terminal, but you can evaluate Smalltalk expressions in it (you can also do that in a Workspace/Playground and many other "text boxes"). That means your "input"/evaluated text must be a valid Smalltalk expression. `Game new board 2 3` is not.

Rather, your board method should take two arguments, like below:

```
boardWithColumns: cols rows: rows
    Transcript cr; show: cols asString, rows asString
```

Note the changed method signature. Unlike in your code, cols and rows are no longer temporary variables, but the arguments of the message send.

You can then evaluate `Game new boardWithColumns: 2 rows: 3` to have these dimensions printed to the Transcript.